# Finding area of a quad within a parallelogram

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

In parallelogram $ABCD$ $CE=ED$. $O$ is the intersection of $AE$ and the bisector of $\angle ABC$. Given $AB=b$, $BC=a$ and $\angle ABO = \alpha$, find the are of $OBCE$. I have given my calculations below and would like to know if it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have extended $AE$ and $BC$, with their intersection point being $K$, as shown below

[image]

As $AB \parallel CE$ it is the median of triangle $ABK$, hence, due to triangle similarity, $BC=CK=a$.

Area of $ABK = absin(2\alpha)$, area of $ECK$ will be $\frac14$ of $ABK$ due to similarity, or $\frac14absin(2\alpha)$.

As $BO$ is a bisector, area $A(ABO)/absin(2\alpha) = b/(b+2a) => A(ABO)=ab^2sin(2\alpha)/(2a+b)$

Area $A(OBCE) = A(ABK)-A(ECK)-A(ABO) = \frac34absin(2\alpha)-ab^2sin(2\alpha)/(2a+b)$

Comment: Please include this in your question and not as an answer.

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

Note: This is essentially what you have done. I found that out after I have the solution written up.

Let [ABO] = X, [the required] = Y, [CEK] = Z.

[image]

By area formula, $X + Y + Z = 0.5(b)(2a) \sin 2 \theta = ab \sin 2 \theta $.

By midpoint theorem, 4Z = X + Y + Z.

Therefore, $Z = \dfrac {ab \sin 2 \theta}{4}$.

By angle bisector theorem, $\dfrac {X}{b} = \dfrac {Y + Z}{2a}$. That is, $2aX = b(Y + Z)$.

Then, $2aX + bX = b(Y + Z) + bX = b(X + Y + Z)$.

That is, $X = \dfrac {b(ab \sin 2 \theta )}{2a + b}$

Y can therefore be found.